# Google Hangouts - controlling other participants video

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm thinking about creating sort of helper application for friend to enjoy paper RPG through internet.
I was thinking about using Hangouts API, however I have.

Is there a way of temporarily exclude some of the participants from running conversation? They can see other data on app, but should hear nor see other participants.
Is there a way of creating a private conversation within group conversation? So private participants will disappear from group, and after finishing the would automatically be reconnected to group conversation?

I'm reviewing Hangouts API, but I'm not finding answers. Or maybe I should  look into WebRTC instead of Hangouts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is... another Hangout or WebRTC session ;). You could always develop your own Hangout Extension to share specific info with selected participants who are also using your extension.

You could also have your Hangout session be the main conversation with all parties, while you use Join.me, Zoom.us or WebRTC to screenshare privately with your friend.